# Injecting value into inner tag

Tags: grails, groovy, taglib

Having two nested tags, How is it possible to inject a variable into inner tag binding?

```
class CriteriaTagLib {

    def criteria = { attrs, body ->
        out << "start"
        out << body.call()
        out << "end"
    }

    def eq = {
        out << "eq${group}"
    }
}
```

And having in a GSP page :

```
<g:criteria>
    <g:eq></g:eq>
<g:criteria>
```

The question is how to set a value for `group` (used inside of `eq`) from inside of `criteria`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<q:criteria>` can put own context/data as a request scope attribute (or page scope), and use it inside by `<q:eq>` (don't forget to remove it on closing tag). Like:

```
static final CONTEXT = this.class.name

def criteria = { attrs, body ->
    def data = [
        group: 'test 1'
    ]
    request.setAttribute(CONTEXT, data)
    out << "start"
    out << body.call()
    out << "end"
    request.removeAttribute(CONTEXT)
}


def child = { attrs, body ->
   def data = request.getAttribute(CONTEXT)
   out << 'eq'
   out << data.group  
}
```

Comment: Already found this solution. What I was looking for is something like groovy binding for inner closures, but it seems that it's not possible with taglib closures.

Comment: Is it possible to develop taglibs in java? Just like `foreach` and similar standard grails tags?

Comment: if you're talking about plain java webapp, you can develop JSP taglib using java

Comment: No, I mean implementing tags like `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyEachTag` that is written using java.

Comment: ok, I got it. Actually I didn't try Java for GSP tags, but I don't see any problems, I believe you can use same approach

Answer (score 0):

The inner tag `eq` has no knowledge of its outer tag `criteria`. But you could achieve something like below,

```
def criteria = { attrs, body ->
    out << "start"
    out << body('hello there')
    out << "end"
}

def eq = {attrs->
    out << "eq${attrs.group}"
}
```

and in the gsp page,

```
<g:criteria>
  <g:eq group="${it}"/>
</g:criteria>
```